# JSF 2 + Quartz scheduling library

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, quartz-scheduler

I have a web application thats using JSF 2. In this application I am using a charting library which is getting data from an xml file, the application updates the xml file, when someone accesses the site, because of jsf 2 Action. Now I want to implement the Quartz library the open source scheduling library, to update the xml file and not rely on the users action, but I have no idea how to call an Action from Quartz using JSF 2.

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking , you should implement your scheduled logic , define when it will run , and initialize your scheduled jobs when the application server starts.

#### Implement scheduled logic

Your scheduled class should implement `org.quartz.Job` interface and override its [execute()](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/Job.html#execute%28org.quartz.JobExecutionContext%29)  which contains the logic of your scheduled  job. In your case , it is the method to update the XML file. You should make this method does not have any dependencies on JSF such that it can be called outside the JSF .

```
public class MyScheduledJob implements Job {

   public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
          updateXML();
   }
}
```

#### Initialize and start Quartz

Quartz provides a `ServletContextListener` called [QuartzInitializerListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/ee/servlet/QuartzInitializerListener.html) that allows you to initialize and start Quartz when the application server starts .

Add this listener to your `web.xml`

```
<listener>
     <listener-class> org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

By default , it will look for a file called `quartz.properties` in the classpath to initialize Quartz .  You can refer [this](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/) for the more info about  configurable options available in `quartz.properties`

#### Define which Job will  run at which time

You can define it in a XML file (Its schema definition can be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd) ) and configure  [XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/plugins/xml/XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.html) in `quartz.properties` to load this XML when Quartz is initialized.

For example , in the `quartz.properties`

> org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class
>   =org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames = **quartz-config.xml**
>   org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true

Then in the **quartz-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <job-scheduling-data
        xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
        version="1.8">

        <schedule>
            <job>
                <name>MyScheduledJob</name>
                <group>MyScheduledGroup</group>
                <description>Job to update XML </description>
                <job-class>com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.MyScheduledJob </job-class>
            </job>

            <trigger>
                    <cron>
                            <name>midNightTrigger</name>
                            <job-name>MyScheduledJob</job-name>
                            <job-group>MyScheduledGroup</job-group>
                            <!-- It will run every night at 3:30 am -->
                            <cron-expression>0 30 3 * * ?</cron-expression>  
                    </cron>
              </trigger>
        </schedule>
    </job-scheduling-data>
```

All the above is for Quartz 'a latest version 2.1 . You can check out the [sample codes](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/examples/) and [tutorials](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/) from Quartz for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to invoke a JSF action from a scheduled job, the job's execute() method will need to include code that makes an HTTP request to the JSF action.  You will likely want to use a code library such as Apache HttpClient or HTTP Unit, if java's  URLConnection class does not easily fit your needs.